# Damaged android studio project

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have built the application many times. But I have a weak laptop so it turned off in the middle. When I went into the project I saw an incomprehensible text that causes errors. it is unrealistic for me to recover manually because there are so many files. Is it possible to recover? I will be unrealistically grateful for your help. Thanks.

Аll files looks like this:

```
<component name="libraryTable">
  <library name="Gradle: com.google.android.datatransport:transport-runtime:3.0.0@aar">
    <CLASSES>
      <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2873c6ed12b257c554ee157979d1b9ba/jetified-transport-runtime-3.0.0/jars/classes.jar!/" />
      <root url="file://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2873c6ed12b257c554ee157979d1b9ba/jetified-transport-runtime-3.0.0/res" />
    </CLASSES>
    <JAVADOC>
      <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.android.datatransport/transport-runtime/3.0.0/7f506fe3498cda976d1b350c218464a0f1974982/transport-runtime-3.0.0-javadoc.jar!/" />
    </JAVADOC>
    <SOURCES />
  </library>
</component>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution would be to work your little butt off and get a better puter